# How can I get the calling method inside WCF's IDispatchMessageInspector?

Tags: wcf

I have a method with custom attribute in my service. I want to read the attributes of the calling method on the server side and check if it has that attribute. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by simply implementing IParameterInspector instead. As the documentation states, parameter inspector works on operation level.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot - the server side cannot go back to the client and read attribute in its code. After all - these could be on different machine, potentially even using different programming languages and system. How is a Java server going to read your .NET client attribute?

Check out figure showing the WCF archicture: on the left, you have the client, on the right, the server, and all that's holding the two together is the messages being exchanged. They have no other link.

[image]

What you could do is send along a custom header from the client to the server - then, your server - no matter what it is - can read that custom header in the message and act accordingly.

Messages are being passed between client and server - that's all the connection the two sides have. Anything in the message (and its headers) can be examined by the server - anything else cannot be checked.

Marc